# Sequlize update where timestamp comparison bug

Tags: datetime, sequelize.js, momentjs

I'm trying to update my model with where conditon which compare timestamp according next code:

```
const example = await myModel.update(
{
  name: arg.name
  price:arg.price
  updateDate:new Date(arg.updateDate)
},{
 where :{
  id :arg.id
  updateDate: {
    [Op.lte]:new Date(arg.UpdateDate)
}}})
```

**arg.updateDate** is a string which is look like: '2022/10/02 15:47:19'

When i run this code repeatedly with the same args, some dates making update although arg.updateDate remain unchanged and it doesnt meet the where condition.

In the terminal, seqluize log seems a bit different, the updateDate changes to a different date. can't figure out why.

this is the where condition printed on terminal:

```
 UPDATE .... WHERE "item_code" = $25 AND "price_update_date" <= '2022-10-02 20:47:19.000 +00:00'
```

As you can see it changed from 15:47 to 20:47.

But ,If i log the arg.updateDate it remain unchanged '2022-10-02T15:47:19.000Z' (due to new Date(arg.updateDate)

Comment: Is your timezone offset equal to +5?

Comment: Nope, utc+2 ...

Comment: I meant on the server side

Comment: sorry for misunderstood , how can i know that? ... 
(when i define timezone on db connection i tried with utc and without nothing and it didnt solved it)

Comment: Can you output `new Date(arg.UpdateDate)` on the server side and show the result?